# I am not able to read a image from Java Code which is hosted in Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: java, image, caching, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

We have image processing server which are running in amazon ec2. We have n-number of instances running our image processing server. Which basically reads the image from origin server which is hosted in amazon cdn.

*The problem here is that the image is loading in browser by directly hitting into it but in Java code we are getting nullpointer exception  as bufferedImage is null. After some time we are able to read the image but it would take a weeks to view. This is rare occurrence but stuck totally . please advice on this*

[image: Image request response header]

> Via:1.1 abc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.0 amazon-instnce-a.com:8080
>   (squid/2.6.STABLE21)

*here **amazon-instnce-a.com:8080** is already terminated and it is no longer available but why we are routed the request to here.*

What way we can code in JAVA 6 to retrieve that image ? We are using below snippet to retrieve the image.

```
    static HttpClient httpClient; 

    static void  getImage(String uri){
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);

        try {
            httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(is);
            if(bufferedImage == null){
                    System.out.println("null"); // we got null here
            }
            is.close();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What URL are you hitting?

Comment: Thank you for reading . Amazon cloud delivery network URL we are hitting . Which is a Image hosted in Amazon CDN.